# Secure way to update UNIX account password using Python as root user?

Tags: python, linux, unix, passwords

Consider a UNIX account `jdoe`.  I want to update `jdoe`'s password using python script running as `root`.  Currently, I am using:

```py
cmd = 'echo "' + username + ":" + new_pass + '" | chpasswd '
os.system(cmd)
```

However, that is an unsafe method.  If someone were to enter `new_pass` as `pass"; rm -rf / #`, that would be disasterous.

Is there a safe and secure way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd modify it so the entered password gets hashed (sha512 is standard on modern Linux systems) and then pass  the hashes value to your cmd.

```
cmd = 'echo "' + username + ":" + new_pass + '" | chpasswd -e'
os.system(cmd)
```

Note the `-e` after `chpasswd`

Fleshing the above suggestion out a little more:

```
import crypt
entered_password = 'pass"; rm -rf / #'
new_password = crypt.crypt(entered_password, '$6$' + 'salt1234')
```

Comment: I am doing `cmd = 'echo "' + username + ":" + sha512(new_pass) + '" | chpasswd -e'`, `os.system(cmd)`, but when I try logging in, `new_pass` is not valid.  What is the default hash for `chpasswd -e`?  It does not appear to be sha256.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about untrusted input, it's better to avoid using `os.system`, since that invokes the shell, and in general, you don't want the shell anywhere near untrusted input.  In addition, you typically want to avoid putting secrets into command-line arguments since they can be read by other users, although since `echo` is *usually* a built-in, this isn't strictly a concern here.

To do this securely, you can use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) instead, like so:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['chpasswd'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(b"username:password")
```

Note that if you need to pass additional arguments to `chpasswd`, you'd do that by adding arguments to the array:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['chpasswd', '-c', 'SHA512'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: This seems to be working with `new_pass = pass"; rm -rf / #`.  I hope I am not overlooking something.

Comment: It should indeed work with an arbitrary password, including a password that contains a shell injection.  That's just a part of the password in that case, not a security vulnerability.

Comment: Surprisingly, this does not work with flask, I can't figure out why.

Comment: Ah, replaceing `proc.stdin.write(...)` with `proc.communicate(input=...)` fixed the problem.